# Sharing to Google+ from Android

Tags: android, google-plus

Does Google+ support sharing from an Android app yet? I wanted to know because I have implemented this for twitter and facebook on my app and would like to do the same for Google+. I did read that they have an API now but it's only for development and testing and apps cannot be published. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The Google+ Android API can be found here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/
- The code snippet for sharing on Google+ is a little ways down that page https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/#share_on_google:

For example, in your XML:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/share_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Share on Google+" />
```

In your Activity:

```
Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
      Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(ExampleActivity.this)
          .setType("text/plain")
          .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform. https://developers.google.com/+")
          .getIntent()
          .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

      startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Very good answer James,I tried using PlusShare.Builder,but it wasn't working.But the ShareCompat class worked.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at this post from [Julia Ferraiol](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JuliaFerraioli)[i](http://PrettyAndSmart.wow?WhatACatch) on the [Google Plus developer blog](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/):

[Sharing Rich Content From Your Android Apps, to Google+ and Beyond](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2012/05/sharing-rich-content-from-your-android.html)